# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance - Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to load data into a table using a foreach but I get the error

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

What could I be doing wrong?

Response looks like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Apple",
   "messages": [
      {
         "id": 7,
         "received": 0
      }
   ]
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show()
{
    $items = Item::with('messages')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('home', compact('items'));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
    <td>{{ $details->messages->id }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the join that you are doing on the `Item` table with the `Messages` table returns a list in the `messages` field. Shown here:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Apple""messages":[{"id":7,"received":0}]}
```

Notice the `[{"id":7,"received":0}]`.

To get the individual ID of a message, you would first need to index into the `messages` list. Or you could change the query to only select one message from each item.

Answer (score 0):

try this $userId = Auth::id(); and then where('user_id', $userId)->get()

Comment: Welcome to SO . Please note that very short answers as this will probably not help the original poster. Please explain it in more detail and include a proper formatted code example.